# Inverse of MurmurHash3

Tags: hash, hashcode, murmurhash, hash-code-uniqueness

I am looking for an inverse function of [MurmurHash3_x64_128](https://github.com/aappleby/smhasher/blob/master/src/MurmurHash3.cpp#L255), as implemented [in this Java version](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/blob/b9d807a446dc27eaa885f4a3a741de63871efdd8/commons/src/main/java/org/infinispan/commons/hash/MurmurHash3.java#L101). Note that the difference is in initializing `h1` and `h2` by xoring the seed with some magic numbers. Also, in fact I am interested only in bits 33 - 64 (as I am trying to find out inverse of [simplified version for 32 -> 32 bits](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/blob/b9d807a446dc27eaa885f4a3a741de63871efdd8/commons/src/main/java/org/infinispan/commons/hash/MurmurHash3.java#L347).

I have found [nice blogpost](http://bitsquid.blogspot.cz/2011/08/code-snippet-murmur-hash-inverse-pre.html) which, regrettably, uses different variants of the algorithm.

According to wiki the algorithm is not cryptographically safe, so inverse should exist.

Comment: Pre-image also exists for cryptographically secure hashes, it's just hard to find.

Comment: Okay, I meant that the inverse function is fast == O(1) for 32 bit numbers.

Comment: did u ever find the answer to this?

Comment: Regrettably not (but TBH I don't remember why I needed that in the first place). Out of curiosity, why do you need that? Related to Infinispan?